# How to find best grouping match combination on postgresql query

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I would like to see if it is possible to solve my problem with a more elegant query than the one I did. Maybe with window analytical functions or something else that I don't know of.

I have tree tables `tablea`, `tableb` and `relation` with the below structure:

```
tablea               tableb                 relation
------------------   -------------------    ----------------
ida integer PK,      idb integer PK,        id_b integer FK
namea varchar(10)    nameb varchar(10)      id_a integer FK
```

The idea is that the `tableb` is the one with the groups and the `relation` table is just the `m-n` relationship between `tablea` and `tableb`

So I have the following data (based on the n-m relation table)

```
group1 ( namea1, namea2, namea3 );
group2 ( namea1, namea5, namea6 );
group3 ( namea1, namea6 );
group4 ( namea6, namea7 );
group5 ( namea7, namea8, namea9 );
group6 ( namea1, namea2, namea5, namea6 );
```

And the user want to create a new group and add names to it (he can only add names that exists on `tablea`). **My goal is to show to this user the closest related groups with the names that he want to add on this new group**

So lets say that the user is creating the `group7` and want to add `'namea1', 'namea6' and 'namea4'` on it. Then I woud show him the groups that already have this combination of words or at least some of then on it. I make this query:

```
select b.nameb, al.names, array_agg(a.namea), count(a.namea) qty
from
   tablea a 
      INNER JOIN relation g on a.ida = g.id_a
      INNER JOIN tableb b on b.idb = g.id_b
      INNER JOIN 
       (select b.idb, b.nameb, array_agg(a.namea) as names
          from tablea a 
               INNER JOIN relation g on a.ida = g.id_a
               INNER JOIN tableb b on b.idb = g.id_b
         group by b.idb, b.nameb) al ON g.id_b = al.idb
where a.namea in ( 'namea1', 'namea6', 'namea4' )
group by b.nameb, al.names
order by b.nameb;
```

Which brings me:

```
Groups     All names on it                 which one he want to add     occur. count
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
group1    (namea1,namea2,namea3)           namea1                       1
group2    (namea1,namea5,namea6)           namea1,namea6                2
group3    (namea1,namea6)                  namea1,namea6                2
group4    (namea6,namea7)                  namea6                       1
group6    (namea1,namea2,namea5,namea6)    namea1,namea6                2
```

Showing him this info will help to decide whether he really needs to create this new group or just change the ones that already exists adding the name that isn't on it (on my example `namea4` in group 2, 3 or 6).

I've created a fiddle example with all this data and with my query. It is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8a63b/3

The query I did solve my problem, what I don't like on it is the fact that I had to repeat the same query to use it as subquery to show all names and which one the user provided is inside it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be simple, [**SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8a63b/17)

```
SELECT
  tableb.nameb AS group_name,
  string_agg( tablea.namea, ', ') as users_in_group,
  string_agg( tablea2.namea, ', ') as want_to_add,
  count(tablea2.ida) as count
FROM
  relation
  JOIN tablea on ( ida = id_a )
  JOIN tableb ON ( idb = id_b )
  LEFT JOIN tablea as tablea2 ON ( tablea2.namea in ('namea1', 'namea6', 'namea4') 
                                  AND tablea2.ida = tablea.ida )
GROUP BY 
  tableb.idb,
  tableb.nameb
HAVING 
   count(tablea2.ida) > 0
ORDER BY 
   tableb.nameb
```

Should get you,

```
| GROUP_NAME |                 USERS_IN_GROUP |    WANT_TO_ADD | COUNT |
|------------|--------------------------------|----------------|-------|
|     group1 |         namea1, namea2, namea3 |         namea1 |     1 |
|     group2 |         namea1, namea5, namea6 | namea1, namea6 |     2 |
|     group3 |                 namea1, namea6 | namea1, namea6 |     2 |
|     group4 |                 namea6, namea7 |         namea6 |     1 |
|     group6 | namea1, namea2, namea5, namea6 | namea1, namea6 |     2 |
```

Comment: Hi @Akash, it is a wrong answer. `USERS_IN_GROUP` and `WANT_TO_ADD` is the same on your result. If you look at the provided data you see that on the group1 column `USERS_IN_GROUP` it should show: `namea1, namea2, namea3`. And so on in the other groups. You are showing just the ones in the filter. Thanks for trying anyway!

Comment: Your answer looks great. But Please, edit the Fiddle. So I will accept it. Plus it has a better execution plain too. :)

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8a63b/4)

```
select *, array_length("want to add", 1) as "ocurrences"
from (
    select
        nameb,
        users_in_group,
        (
            select array_agg(namea)
            from unnest(users_in_group) a(namea)
            where namea = any (array['namea1', 'namea6', 'namea4']::varchar(10)[])

        ) as "want to add"
    from (
        select
            b.nameb, array_agg(a.namea) as users_in_group
        from
            tablea a 
            inner join
            relation g on a.ida = g.id_a
            inner join
            tableb b on b.idb = g.id_b
        group by b.nameb
    ) s
    where
        array['namea1', 'namea6', 'namea4']::varchar(10)[] && users_in_group
) s
order by nameb
```

Comment: Thanks @ClodoaldoNeto, I will wait a little longer to see if someone else add an answer. Personally I don't like a subquery as an element on the select elements, in my point of view it difficults the reading. But your solution is a little better than my own on the execution plan, so I will use it and mark it as the right answer if no one add another answer. Thanks again. :)